# Проблема с запросом

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Возникла такая проблема. Имеется вот такой код:

```
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("show tables like '$buildid'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        echo $result;
```

Мне нужно узнать, что выводит этот запрос из БД, т.к нужно сделать проверку на то, имеется ли таблица, если нет - то создать. 
Запрос вроде верный, пробовал без кавычек. 
Но проблема такова: `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /home/v/vupseen/vupseen.beget.tech/public_html/push/DbOperation.php on line 28`

Как мне получить что-либо на выходе из этого запроса?

Comment: Вообще в идеале мне нужно сделать всё это так:
Если есть такая таблица, то вернуть цифру 0, если нет, то 1.

Answer (score 1):

Очень сложно прочесть ошибку? В ней все написано по какой причине ошибка

> Объект класса mysqli_result не может быть преобразован к строке

Вот сигнатура класса [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php)